# How can I cast a query result to string and insert it into a table row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm getting an error that the subquery returns more than one value and I know it does so now I would like to cast that subquery result to a string and then insert that string into the table on the same position

I've already tried with a loop but since I can't use loops anywhere else than outside the query it didn't help much.

That is the query I'm working with

```
SELECT DISTINCT LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email, Firstname, Lastname, dbo.spValueToString(Subscribed) AS Subscribed,

dbo.spValueToString((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    WHERE tblEmailBlackList.Email = LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email and tblEmailBlackList.PortalID = -2)) As GeneralBlockList,

(SELECT DISTINCT PortalLocalization.PortalName
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    LEFT JOIN tblLiveCampaignSettings ON tblLiveCampaignSettings.ModuleID = tblEmailBlackList.ModuleID
    LEFT JOIN PortalLocalization ON PortalLocalization.PortalID = tblEmailBlackList.PortalID AND PortalLocalization.CultureCode = 'sl-SI'
    LEFT JOIN #tmp ON tblEmailBlackList.Email = #tmp.Email COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
    WHERE LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email = #tmp.Email COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
    AND tblEmailBlackList.PortalID >= 0 OR tblEmailBlackList.PortalID =- 1)
    AS LocalBlockList

FROM LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email
```

And this is the part I need to be casted into a string:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT PortalLocalization.PortalName
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    LEFT JOIN tblLiveCampaignSettings ON tblLiveCampaignSettings.ModuleID = tblEmailBlackList.ModuleID
    LEFT JOIN PortalLocalization ON PortalLocalization.PortalID = tblEmailBlackList.PortalID AND PortalLocalization.CultureCode = 'sl-SI'
    LEFT JOIN #tmp ON tblEmailBlackList.Email = #tmp.Email COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
    WHERE LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email = #tmp.Email COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
    AND tblEmailBlackList.PortalID >= 0 OR tblEmailBlackList.PortalID =- 1)
```

Result would be a string which is then inserted into the table in the same row as the result of this subquery should be

Comment: Then you need to give us logic by which we can limit this query to returning only a single row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean by that?

Comment: So you want to aggregate all `PortalName` returned from the query you gave, separated by something (so say if it returns two rows - 'A' and 'B', you want it to be 'A, B'?) and then insert it where?

Comment: @MarcinJ yeah there can be more than one PortalName returned and i want all to be in one row and the insert would be at the same place as the result of the subquery would be. I'm gonna add a bit more code to that

Comment: which SQL Server version? Could you please add sql-server-<version> tag?

Comment: Added it @MarcinJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Tried that STUFF function but I still get that the subquery returned more than one value @MarcinJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to aggregate the returned rows into a single one. Since you're on SQL Server 2014, STRING_AGG is not available, so we will use the [XML aggregation trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005). Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email, Firstname, Lastname, dbo.spValueToString(Subscribed) AS Subscribed,

dbo.spValueToString((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    WHERE tblEmailBlackList.Email = LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email and tblEmailBlackList.PortalID = -2)) As GeneralBlockList,
STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + PortalLocalization.PortalName
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    LEFT JOIN tblLiveCampaignSettings ON tblLiveCampaignSettings.ModuleID = tblEmailBlackList.ModuleID
    LEFT JOIN PortalLocalization ON PortalLocalization.PortalID = tblEmailBlackList.PortalID AND PortalLocalization.CultureCode = 'sl-SI'
    LEFT JOIN #tmp ON tblEmailBlackList.Email = #tmp.Email COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
    WHERE LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email = #tmp.Email COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
    AND tblEmailBlackList.PortalID >= 0 OR tblEmailBlackList.PortalID =- 1
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    AS LocalBlockList

FROM LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email
```

Comment: That solves it thanks! Also just noticed that I will have to use UNION and I think that won't work with FOR XML but I will try to work around it